# Rails, minitest: How to test the output of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

My controller looks like this:

```
class CalculatorController < ApplicationController

  def calculate
    money = params[:money].to_f
   @worktime =  divide(money, 25)
  end

  private

  def divide(money, worktime)
    output = money/worktime
  end
end
```

I wrote a Test like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CalculatorControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "response" do
    get calculate_path
    assert_equal 200, response.status
  end
end
```

This test passes. Now, I want to write a test, to check, whether the output is correct. I tried this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CalculatorControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "response" do
    get calculate_path(money: 25)
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal 1, @response.worktime
  end
end
```

But this error occurs: `NoMethodError: undefined method`worktime'`

How do I test the output of the controller? ( In my case @worktime)

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  In Rails 4, you can check this.  In Rails 5, you have to bring another piece in to do what you want to do.

Comment: @MichaelChaney Rails 5.0.0.1 What piece do I need to bring in? Thank you

Comment: See my answer below, too much for a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good writeup here on the changes to testing in Rails 5:
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html

In Rails 4, you would use "assigns" to check that:

```
assert_equal 1, assigns(:worktime)
```

You can still have this functionality by including the rails-controller-testing gem https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing in your Gemfile in the test group.  More here from dhh:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I test my method 'divide'? For example: assert_equal 1, divide(25/25).

Comment: I can't say without seeing more of your application (and that's getting beyond the scope of SO at that point, anyway), but generally such logic should likely be in a model where it can be unit tested.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby `@variables` are instance variables. Not globals. Instance variables are always private*.

So `@worktime` is an instance variable that belongs to `CalculatorController` - not `CalculatorControllerTest`.

Ruby lets you access an instance variable without declaring it.

So this example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CalculatorControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "response" do
    get calculate_path(money: 25)
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal 1, @response.worktime
  end
end
```

Is actually in practice:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CalculatorControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "response" do
    get calculate_path(money: 25)
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal 1, nil.worktime # since @worktime is not declared in this scope.
  end
end
```

Previously you could pry into the inner workings of the controller with `assigns` which was removed in Rails 5. You can restore it [with a gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) but for new applications you should use a different approach to testing - you should instead test your controllers by testing the actual output in terms of response codes and JSON or HTML output. Not how it does its job.

```
require 'test_helper'

class CalculatorControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "response" do
    get calculate_path(money: 25)
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_select "#result", "1"
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you give me a working example? Or a website for further instructions? Thank you